# Google Play Billing API for Xamarin .NET?

Tags: android, xamarin, billing

I need to use the Google Play Billing API, in an Android app that I am building with Visual Studio Xamarin.

All the documentation I've found references Android Studio and build.gradle, which I don't have.

I've searched high & low for a Visual Studio answer to this, but I must be missing something because I have found nothing.

Any suggestions would be welcome on how to use the Google Play Billing API, in an Android app.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin

Comment: You could check the sample in the link. A C# Google Play client of Google Play Billing, for use with Xamarin.Android applications.https://github.com/ddebilt/play.billing.v3